# Implementation of function "append" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append

I want to implement function "append" from jQuery on JavaScript with using DOM methods. I have a constructor of $ function:

`

```
function $(selector){
  if ( !(this instanceof $)){
    return new $(selector);
  }
  this.selectors = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
};
```

`

And i want to implement this function. Always like here: http://api.jquery.com/append/
`

```
$.prototype.append = function(code){
//code here
}
```

`

Thank you, for yours answers

Comment: Have you taken a look at the append function from the jQuery library, if that's what you're looking to emulate? The uncompressed version very clearly shows exactly how its being done.

Comment: You could have a look how jQuery solved this task.

Comment: `.selectors` should be called `.elements`.

Comment: So, what is `code`? What have you tried?